# Magit: Not visible selected region

Tags: magit

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Magit.

If I want to select some regin in *scratch* buffer I use `Shift arrow` (or by mouse). It's work fine. 
Here example:

[image: Selected_region]

Now I want to select text in Magit:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

And do this by `Shift arrow` or by mouse.

Here result:

[image: Not_selected_region]

Why region is not select? It's very uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

Magit displays the "magit selection" instead of the region, which is a slightly larger area than the region. This is described in the doc-string of the option `magit-keep-region-overlay`. You can set that option to `t` to always visualize the region.